# Filling text outlines in Direct3D

Tags: text, directx, gdi+, rendering, direct3d

I'm suprised that Google doesn't shed much light on this.

I'm creating a simple CAD viewer using Direct3D. Because of it's nature (zoom functionality etc) text elements must be vector text; I can't use textured polys.

I've called into gdi32.dll to get the glyphs and create quite reasonable text outlines from straight lines and bezier curves, however the text isn't solid and the points aren't necessarily regular in any way. Enclosing characters (b, p, o, A, etc) actually have more than one seperate outline.

As a consequence, I can't just shoot the points into a vertex buffer and specify a primitive type.

All I can do at the moment is render the outlines as line strips, resulting in hallow text.

Can anyone suggest a good strategy for rendering solid vector text with their outlines?

Note that I interpolate the bezier curves into point lists (A lot of people use shaders/witchcraft).

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what version of DirectX you are using, but the utility function [D3DXCreateText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172799%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will create a 3D mesh for a given text in any TrueType font. If you want a 2D version, simply use no or minimal extrusion, and straight-on orthogonal projection.

If you need explicit outlines, you might be able to either (a) combine this approach with the Outline you already have, (b) draw the text twice at a slightly different scale (depending on current zoom level) or (c) use shaders to draw a pixel-perfect outline.

A screenshot of the exact look-and-feel you are after might help. My CAD drawings all have solid text, no outlines.

Comment: Direct3D 9 via SlimDX, however I can't seem to find D3DXCreateText anywhere in it; I'm presuming they haven't exposed it.

Comment: According to the source, SlimDX exposes it through [Mesh.CreateText()](http://slimdx.mdxinfo.com/latestdocs/Default.aspx?topic=Class+Reference%2fSlimDX.Direct3D9+Namespace%2fMesh+Class).

Answer (score 0):

I am creating text meshes with D3DXCreateText (Win32, DX9). They rotate nicely. However, they always seem to be the same size regardless of the height of the font that has been selected in the DC.

The mesh lines in smaller characters are aliased and don't look good on video cards without multisampling.